# Using PERCENT_RANK in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone explain the mathematics behind Percent_Rank() in Oracle SQL.

```sql
SELECT ID, principal_disbursed, DUE_DATE, CREDIT_OFFICER, 
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY principal_disbursed)
FROM TABLE1
```

I need to understand the calculation running in the background.

| id | principal_disbursed | principal_repaid | due_date | repayment_date | credit_officer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $334 | $334 | 12/10/2017 | 17/10/2017 | John |
| 2 | $184 | $184 | 10/11/2018 | 20/10/2018 | Maria |
| 3 | $417 | $417 | 18/08/2017 | 24/08/2017 | Maria |
| 4 | $500 | $500 | 04/08/2017 | 14/07/2017 | Maria |
| 5 | $250 | $250 | 04/08/2017 | 06/08/2017 | John |

Comment: You can find this info in Oracle FAQ here - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that might give you a hint. I have removed the dates.

```
with data(id,   principal_disbursed,    principal_repaid,   credit_officer) as (
select 1,   334,    334,'John' from dual union all
select 2,   184,    184,'Maria' from dual union all
select 3,   417,    417,'Maria' from dual union all
select 4,   500,    500,'Maria' from dual union all
select 5,   250,    250,'John' from dual
)
,cnt as (
select count(*)-1 cnt
from data
)
,one as (
SELECT ID, principal_disbursed, CREDIT_OFFICER
from data 
order by principal_disbursed
)
select one.*, case when rownum=1 then 0 else (rownum-1)/(select cnt from cnt) end
from one 
;
```

That is the same as :

```
with data(id,   principal_disbursed,    principal_repaid,   credit_officer) as (
select 1,   334,    334,'John' from dual union all
select 2,   184,    184,'Maria' from dual union all
select 3,   417,    417,'Maria' from dual union all
select 4,   500,    500,'Maria' from dual union all
select 5,   250,    250,'John' from dual
)
SELECT ID, principal_disbursed, CREDIT_OFFICER, 
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY principal_disbursed)
FROM data
```